# What is RouteComponentProps?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

When I was searching for information about react, I saw `RouteComponentProps` like

```
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';
const ~~~: React.FC<RouteComponentProps>
```

and

```
class BookingSiteOverview extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}>
```

So I searched `RouteComponentProps`, but given information is too fragmented. `RouteComponentProps` is mentioned in Q&A only briefly.

I want to know what is this. What is it for and how to use it?

Please give me advice.

Answer (score 6):

`RouteComponentProps` looks to be a Typescript interface definition of react-router-dom's [route-props](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props).

The `RouteComponentProps` prop-types definition may've been part of react-router-dom but isn't currently exported. I found the Typescript export in [Definitely Typed](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/eafef8bd049017b3998939de2edbab5d8a96423b/types/react-router/index.d.ts#L69-L74).

```
export interface RouteComponentProps<Params extends { [K in keyof Params]?: string }> {
  match: match<Params>;
  location: H.Location;
  history: H.History;
  staticContext?: any;
}
```

This is just the way to define the react propTypes in Typescript, via interfaces.

Comment: If you need to use the `History` type in TypeScript, it needs to be imported from a library that react-router-dom uses: [history](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/history)